# Innerproduct of <a+b, c> = <c, c> where c != 0

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, inner-products

Say we have 3 non zero vectors a,b,c.
If (a + b, c) = (c, c), can we conclude that a + b = c?

Here is my attempt to prove the claim:
a + b != 0, since (a + b, c) is non zero.

I tried subtracting (c , c) from each side:

(a + b, c) - (c ,c) = (c , c) - (c , c)

(a + b - c,c) = 0 -> a + b-c = 0 -> a + b = c.

Is the proof correct?
edit: The proof is not correct since (a+b-c,c) = 0 does not imply that a+b-c = 0.

Comment: Some of your symbols have disappeared into the ether. You should fix your post.

Comment: No you cannot. $\langle u,v\rangle = \lVert u\rVert\lVert v\rVert\cos \theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between them. You need only choose an $a+b$ so that $\lVert a+b\rVert\cos\theta =\lVert c\rVert$ which is easily done.

Comment: It is clearly not true that $<a+b,c>=<c,c>\implies a+b=c$.  just take any vector $\vec v$ orthogonal to $c$ and let $a+b=\vec v +c$.

Comment: To be complete:  your argument fails because $<\vec v,c>=0$ does not imply that $\vec v=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equality of two inner products does not imply equality of the vectors. Take $c=(1,1,-1)^T$. Then $\langle c,c\rangle =3$. Let $a+b=(0,0,-3)^T$. Then again $\langle a+b,c\rangle=3$, but $a+b\neq c$.

Comment: I can see that the statement is incorrect, due to the counter examples (thanks!).  Where does the proof I posted fail?
Thanks!

Comment: In the last line. You say that $(w,c)=0$ implies $w=0$. Certainly not true in general.

Comment: I see, it's because w (a+b-c in my proof) could be orthogonal to c. Makes sense! thanks a lot